Log has this error : main.CRITICAL: Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\ReCaptchaUi\Model\CaptchaTypeResolver,
My log is full of the following error and im not sure why. I have switched off recaptcha in the backend too just in case it's related but i don't think so.
Not sure what to do.

main.CRITICAL: Type Error occurred when creating object:
Magento\ReCaptchaUi\Model\CaptchaTypeResolver,
Magento\ReCaptchaUi\Model\CaptchaTypeResolver::__construct(): Argument
#1 ($resolvers) must be of type array, null given, called in /var/www/vhosts/xxx/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php
on line 121 [] []


Any other place re-capcha is enable?

Remove the vendor folder and then run
composer install

It will download the correct required packages. once done check if you need to apply any patches for your code. if so, run the following command
./vendor/bin/ece-tools apply

once done, run the following commands
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean

if still there is any error, do let me know here.

If the ReCaptcha module files are corrupted or not fully installed, the dependency injection system might fail to properly provide the needed dependencies. Try re-installing the ReCaptcha module:
composer remove magento/module-recaptcha-ui
composer require magento/module-recaptcha-ui
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean

Try to disable third-party modules one by one to see if the issue persists, especially any modules related to ReCaptcha or CAPTCHA functionality.
It can be also cache issue:
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
rm -rf var/generation/* var/di/* generated/*
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

